# Implementing channels in haskell -- Tackling the awkward squad

Tags: haskell, concurrency, squad

In the paper [Tackling the awkward squad](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/marktoberdorf/mark.pdf), Simon Peyton Jones has provided a "possible implementation" of a `Channel`.

```hs
type Channel a = (MVar (Stream a) , -- Read end
                  MVar (Stream a) ) -- Write end (the hole)

type Stream a = MVar (Item a)

data Item a = MkItem a (Stream a)
```

Now, he implements a function `putChan :: Channel a -> a -> IO ()` like this

```hs
putChan (read, write) val
  = do { new_hole <- newEmptyVar ;
         old_hole <- takeMVar write ;
         putMVar write new_hole ;
         putMVar old_hole (MkItem val new_hole) }
```

The function above takes a MVar out of write, then puts an empty MVar into it.
Then it writes to the old_hole it extracted from write.

The question is, why does it write to old_hole? It has been taken out from write and its scope is limited to the current block only, then what difference does it make?

Comment: I wrote my understanding of channels from the referenced paper here: https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/631ee428ddcf1222b8b5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The question is, why does it write to old_hole? It has been taken out from write and its scope is limited to the current block only, then what difference does it make?

Not quite. `old_hole` is "in scope" on *the read side*. You have to look at `newChan` for the full picture:

```
newChan = do { 
    read <- newEmptyMVar ;
    write <- newEmptyMVar ;
    hole <- newEmptyMVar ;
    putMVar read hole ;
    putMVar write hole ;
    return (read,write) }
```

So right after calling `newChan` the "`old_hole`" from `putChan` is the same `MVar` as `hole` in `newChan`. And as channel operations progress, that `old_hole` is always somewhere nested in the `MVar`s of `read`.

I found the design of linked list-style channels truly difficult to wrap my head around at first. The illustration from that paper does a decent job of showing the structure, but the basic idea is readers "peel off" a layer of MVar to reveal a value, while writers are inserting values "at the bottom" of the pile of MVars, mainting a pointer to the bottom-most one.

By the way this is the design used in [Control.Concurrent.Chan](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/Control-Concurrent-Chan.html#Chan)